# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline - specifying the workspace directory before node allocates the workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've got a multibranch pipeline, defined in a scripted pipeline (from a library) that is coordinating ~100 builds, each build across multiple slaves (different operating systems).  One of the Operating systems is Windows, which has a 255 character path limitation.  Because some of our jobs have ~200 character paths in them (which we can't control because it is a vendor provided hell), i need to change the step/node workspace on our windows slaves, ideally changing it with the node() step, so that git is automatically checked out only once into the custom workspace.

I've tried all kinds of various styles:

This works in the Declarative Pipeline:

```
stage('blah') {
    node {
        label 'win'
        customWorkspace "c:\\w\\${JOB_NAME"
    }
    steps {
        ...
    }
}
```

But i can't find the equivalent for scripted pipelines:

```
pipeline {
    stage('stage1') {
        node('win-node') {
             // the git repository is checked out to ${env.WORKSPACE}, but it's unusable due to the path length issue
             ws("c:\\w\\${JOB_NAME}") {
                 // this switches the workspace, but doesn't clone the git repo again
                 body()
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, i'd like something like this:

```
pipeline {
    stage('stage1') {
        node('win-node', ws="c:\\w\\${JOB_NAME}") {
            body()
        }
    }
}
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Where does the git checkout happen? If it’s inside the ws block it should get checked out there.

Comment: The node block does the git checkout automatically in the default workspace

Answer (score 0):

Not tested (specially define options inside node), but you could try to skip default checkout and do it after changing the workspace, something like this:

```
pipeline {
    stage('stage1') {
        node('win-node') {
            options {
                skipDefaultCheckout true // prevent checkout to default workspace
            }
            ws("c:\\w\\${JOB_NAME}") {
                checkout scm // perform default checkout here
                body()
            }
        }
    }
}
```